# How Random Forest and XGB 'Regressor' calculate feature importance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, xgboost, feature-selection

I am searching about how Random Forest and XGB 'regressor' calculate feature importance.
However, the most of discussion focus on Classifier.

I try to find out the answer in the official document but got some question.

1. In [XGB official site](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html), the description of get_score indicate
   that 'For linear model, only “weight” is defined and it’s the
   normalized **coefficients** without bias.'   Dose it means the feature
   importance is calculated only by the coefficients between input and
   output? Not calculated by mse or gini?
2. In [RF official site](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html), the description of feature_importances_
   indicates that 'The *impurity-based* feature importances.'  But in the
   [RF source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2beed5584/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L1203) line 1125, it noted that 'Supported criteria are
   "mse" for the mean squared error, which is equal to variance
   reduction as feature selection criterion'   Dose RF regressor apply
   impurity-based or mse for feature importance calculation?

I consider gini impurity as a criteria for classification, so the illustration above confused me.

It will be helpful if sometime can give me a guide for how to understand these documents.
For example, how to trace which function did I run.

Thank you!

Comment: I think it would be better if you asked this question in another community, such as CrossValidated or DataScience.

Comment: If you could also add your code, it would be easier to help you out. For instance - do you really use linear model for XGBoost? Also, I'd suggest looking at 'importance_type' parameter in `xgboost.XGBRegressor` class - there you might find information that you need.

Answer (score 0):

clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(df.drop('name', axis=1), df['name'])

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.bar(df.drop('name', axis=1).columns, height=clf.feature_importances_, bottom = 0, width=0.8)
plt.xticks(rotation=80)

hight_rate_col = df.drop('name', axis=1).columns[clf.feature_importances_ > 0.1]
x_train_rate, x_test_rate, y_train_rate, y_test_rate = train_test_split(df[hight_rate_col], df['name'])

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).